# Starting Out a Novel

Tags: fiction, novel

Would it be more effective to the reader to start out a novel explaining the setting and scenery or, introducing the characters?

Comment: Is the book about the trees, or the people who walk beneath them?

Comment: This depends on what kind of story you're telling, what you're trying to accomplish, possibly the norms of the genre you're writing in, and probably a bunch of other things.  I'm putting this on hold for now; please [edit] to describe your situation in more detail.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readers are different and enjoy different things. And stories are different and require different beginnings.

That said, most people are more interested in persons than in environments, and character driven plots sell better.

But it is best if you don't perceive this as either-or, but rather try to introduce both the character and the setting at the same time. All great novels begin with (1) the most intimate concerns of (2) one character (3) living in a certain situation. All three -- character, environment, and "problem" -- make up the story, and they can (and in my opinion should be) present right from the first paragraph.

Pick some recent bestsellers and read their first pages to see how these three aspects might be integrated.

Answer (score 1):

In response to SaberWriters comment, I'd like to raise the question what a story is. As a a trained physicist, the answer to me is easy: Change, or, in the pysical setting, d/dt. Anything that is different at the end of the story from what it was at the beginning of the story can possibily maintain a story.

This element - the aspect that changes - is what you should introduce at the beginning of your story. In my experience, this is essential, because you need to establish a benchmark that allows your reader to judge the wonderful changes happening in your story. If you take away this benchmark, you remove the context of the entire story.

Coming back to SaberWriter and incorporating the change idea means that, as SaberWriter pointed out, you need to know what your story is about. Is it about the transformation of a single character? (This usually is a Hero's Journey.) Introduce the character and stress the character traits that will have changed in the end. Is it about a societal change? Show the society in question. A country? A landscape? Well then, go ahead, and show your reader the status quo, before everything changes.

Comment: Many, especially children's books, are not about change but about  (a) *neutralizing change* and maintaining the status quo (the monsters under the bed are friendly) or (b) showing things *as they are* (Sally visits the dentist).

Comment: I strongly disagree. I could fill pages with the reasons for my oppinion, but at this point, just let me quote what a famous author of children's books once said (I can't remember whether it was Astrid Lindgren or Andreas Steinhöfel or someone else): Children are not stupid. There is no need to gloss over any nasty parts of life for them, even if it is unpleasant. The art of an author of children's books is to tell the story from a point of view that children can understand. That is _not_ equal to treating them like retards.

Comment: I was speaking of children's books, not MG or YA. A book that explains to three year olds what a dentist does does not treat children like retards. Nevertheless that book has neither conflict nor change. And there are a million children's books like that: about animals, construction sites, friendship, and so on and so forth. Explaining the world. Why you should think that such books treat children as if they were stupid is beyond me.

Comment: Then we talked about different things. I was thinking about children that would actively pick up a book to _read a story_. There is nothing wrong with "books that explain the world" - but to me, there is no actual stories in these books. Plus, if my tone offended you, I apologize. It's just that I think that good books for children - think of the Bartimaeus trilogy or Lindgren's books - are something that we, as the literary community, should treasure. Yet, rarely do these books get the recognition they deserve. That makes me angry.

Comment: I'm surprised by the lack of support for this answer. Virtually every story I've ever read, watched, heard, played or written does this in some way or other. I think this is why Lord of the Rings starts out by showing us how sheltered the hobbits lives are from the rest of the world, rather than by introducing us to the main characters: because (at least in my view) it's the relationship of the hobbits to the rest of the world that the story is really about.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's better to start with neither; start with the story. Both setting and character should be introduced bit by bit, as the story begins to unfold. If you start with setting the scene or introducing the characters then the reader has to wait for you to finish before they get to read the story.

Many publishers will only read the first few lines of a piece, and many readers will only read the first page or two, before deciding whether to continue. If your piece doesn't set the stage for the story (better to be left after page one wondering who this is and what that is, than to know but not know that it's important) people will get bored.

This is where prologues are especially useful; if you know you have to set the scene and the character start with a prologue that gives the reader a taste of the action. Get the reader hooked before you start filling bits out.

And as a final note, it's worth remembering:

**If you stop to describe the scenery, the story stops to wait for you.**

Answer (score 0):

This question is analogous to the painting artist asking, should I use light blue, medium blue or dark blue for the sky I am painting?

The answer is: use the color that the sky appears.  You might say,

> "Well, the painter just looks at the sky and paints it the color he
> sees so that is a different thing."

But the **best painters do not only paint what is there**, but *instead paint what they **want you to see***.

**Paint What You Want the Reader to See**

That should also be the way you, the writer, should paint your scenes.  Paint what you want the reader to see.

If setting is extremely important as it is in, [All Quiet On The Western Front, by Erich Maria Remarque -- amazon link](http://amzn.to/2px65b2).

If that setting were changed, since the book is based upon World War I, the entire story would be changed.

Meanwhile, a book like, [John Kennedy Toole's Confederacy of Dunces, (amazon link)](http://amzn.to/2pYtIuT) is a character-driven novel with events occurring because of who the main character is and his outlook on life.

Read the beginning of each of those and you'll see how different they are and how fitting the beginnings are for each book.

In conclusion your answer can be obtained by asking yourself:

> Am I writing a character-driven book?
>
> Am I writing a book that comes from a story concept I have in mind?
>
> Am I writing a book which richly describes some setting / historical period?

The one you seem to gravitate toward is the answer to your question.